# Not understanding auto layout, constraints and size classes

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I'm a bit stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'll give you a quick overview. I have designs for a screen that were built in sketch using an iphone 6 screen size, then redesigned to fit and look right for an iphone 5/5s/5c, and 6 plus as those are the only devices that I want to support.

But the design portion or implementing the designs for just one specific screen size is easy and I understand that part. Where am I'm lost completely, is how to implement a design in one view controller that looks the way that it should in all the screen sizes I designed for.

I've gone through more than a few auto layout and size class tutorials and not sure how I properly use them so that the app recognizes "this is an iphone 5, use these image sizing and placements instead, and this is an iphone 6 plus, use these" and so on.

Everything I've seen to this point regarding auto layout and constraints only use 1 set of numbers to judge distance from elements for example, but all screen sizes would have different distances.

What am I missing or not understanding? I know I'm looking at something improperly.

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that just one set of numbers could be used to judge distances, but this can still describe how a view should appear on different screen sizes. Your problem may be that you're thinking of constraints as describing the frame of your view? (Which obviously has to be different on every device). I find it more helpful to think of constraints as describing how each edge of my view relates to another view.

For example here's a view controller I setup with all the same constraints and how it would look on different devices. The constraints describe how the large grey view is pinned it's left and right edges 20 points from the left and right edges of its container view. It's pinned to 8 points from the top and 8 points from the top of the label. The label is centred vertically and horizontally and it has intrinsic content size. Each button is pinned 20 points from the bottom edge with button 1 and 2 being pinned to the 20 point from the left and right edges respectively.

[image]

I don't know if that helped or if that wasn't the answer you were after and you need to arrange your views differently depending on the device: you can tell Xcode which device size and orientation the constraints you're creating are for, using this button in Interface Builder.

[image]

Use it to select a device size/orientation. After, any constraints you create will only be used on that device. By default any width and height are selected so normally your constraints are applied to all devices.

**Also, you cannot choose which devices you want to support, only the iOS version.**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that did help change my perspective a bit. I'm still struggling with a few things but your example helped me understand a piece of it from earlier.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. What were the other things you were struggling with?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that did help change my perspective a bit. I'm still struggling with a few things but your example helped me understand a piece of it from earlier.

What I'm still struggling with figuring it, is if I still have 3 different size buttons for example for the 5 and 6, 6 + sizes, how I determine the mathematical constraints for each size and if I have three screens to build for, how does the code know which button size to show if I can only plug in 1 set of constraints? Or is it more of an "experiment until it looks right" kinda of game?

Comment: In your example you used a `UIButton`, however these have a an implicit content size (its size it dependent on it's text and font) so you shouldn't be manually setting its size. When I'm creating constraints I basically think, for example, I want this button to be pinned to the bottom, left side on every screen size and the create constraints that will do that. If you could give me a more specific example I might be able to help more.

Comment: Also, no, you shouldn't need to experiment once you've got some more experience. However, to begin with it can be useful to experiment to see the kind of things you can do with AutoLayout, I know I certainly did.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, I was traveling and trying to figure this out. Good news, I pretty much got it down and have started to understand the concepts. Your replies were a BIG help, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Awesome, I hope your projects go well! It's definitely a good feeling when you understand something you've been grappling with. Would you consider giving the answer an up-vote or mark it as correct if you feel either of these apply?

Comment: I've tried and am still short 4 more reputation points before I can vote but have accepted the answers. As soon I have hit 15 (shortly) I will be able to vote it up as it really was the answer I was looking for :).

Comment: Voted. Thank you again for all the help, it made a big difference! :)